# Measuring units for Android UI Design

Tags: interface-design, mobile, android, adobe-xd

I am designing a mobile app for the Android OS. I am currently using Adobe XD. What is the base screen size that I can use to start designing so that 1px is equal to 1dp or 1sp. Also what is the difference between px dp and sp?

Comment: have you checked these questions? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/how-to-prepare-what-all-sizes-and-resolutions-mockups-and-ui-graphics-for-an-a https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71745/andoid-style-guide-px-to-dp-how-do-i-convert/ https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63191/what-is-dpi-and-how-to-use-it-in-android-app-design/63203#63203

Answer (score 0):

Check this website for some generic device metrics.
https://material.io/resources/devices/

When you are designing for apps, you're actually designing in dp but all programs call it px.

If you take the dp and times it by the density you will get the px for the screen.

An example of this is retina screen which has 2x pixel density, so it's fitting in 2 pixels per dp.